# Как нормально склеить более двух видео через moviepy

Tags: python, moviepy

Написал функцию для склеивания видео:

```
    def concat_video(self, name, *args):
    r_videos = []
    for video in args:
        v = VideoFileClip(video)
        r_videos.append(v)
    try:
        final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(r_videos[:])
        final_clip.write_videofile(f"{name}.mp4")
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Ничего не вышло :(")
        print(ex)
```

Когда скидываю два видео все работает нормально, но если передавать три и более, некоторые видео ломаются: начинают скакать вверх вниз, либо появляются черные полосы, звуковые дорожки могут наезжать друг на друга